# use .env file with docker

Tags: node.js, docker, environment-variables

I started to use Docker and 'Dockerized' my Next.js project, how Docker acts with an `.env` file? I have an `.env` file that contains my DB login information/URI, now since Docker copying all the content of the project directory, I guess yarn reading the .env file, but is it really works like that? and is it secured? (since the docker image contains the `.env` file(?)
I saw the only way to send ENV values is by writing them inside the `Dockerfile` file as `ENV name value` but i think its not really secured that way either(?)
Thanks!

Comment: Could you share your dockerfile content please

Answer (score 0):

from what i have read, you could just add `Dockerfile` to list of ignored files in `.dockerignore` so it wont be copied to docker image. correct me if im wrong